# Custom user control looks different when added to window

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I created a custom user control, and it looks like this:

[image: User Control]

XAML for the control is:

```
<Grid>
    <Label Content="Job #"    Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,14,0,0"  Name="label1" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
    <Label Content="Customer" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,41,0,0"  Name="label2" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
    <Label Content="Location" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,68,0,0"  Name="label3" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
    <Label Content="Crossing" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,95,0,0"  Name="label4" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
    <Label Content="Engineer" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,122,0,0" Name="label5" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
    <Label Content="Probe #"  Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,149,0,0" Name="label6" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="48" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />

    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,14,0,0"  Name="lblJob"      Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,41,0,0"  Name="lblCustomer" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,68,0,0"  Name="lblLocation" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,95,0,0"  Name="lblCrossing" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,122,0,0" Name="lblEngineer" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="53,149,0,0" Name="lblProbe"    Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

    <Label Content="Away"        Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="204,41,0,0"  Name="label14" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" />
    <Label Content="Elevation"   Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="204,68,0,0"  Name="label15" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" />
    <Label Content="Right"       Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="204,95,0,0"  Name="label16" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" />
    <Label Content="Inclination" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="204,122,0,0" Name="label17" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" />
    <Label Content="Baseline"    Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="204,149,0,0" Name="label18" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="55" />

    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="258,41,0,0"  Name="lblAway"        Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="258,68,0,0"  Name="lblElevation"   Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="258,95,0,0"  Name="lblRight"       Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="258,122,0,0" Name="lblInclination" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="258,149,0,0" Name="lblBaseline"    Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

    <Label Content="Entry"   Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="338,12,0,0" Name="label13"  Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" />
    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="377,12,0,0" Name="lblEntry" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

    <Label Content="Exit"    Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="521,12,0,0" Name="label25" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" />
    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="560,12,0,0" Name="lblExit" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

    <Label Content="Units"   Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="706,12,0,0" Name="label27"  Style="{StaticResource MyLabel2}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="40" />
    <Label Content="Default" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="745,12,0,0" Name="lblUnits" Style="{StaticResource MyLabel3}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />

    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Height="275" Margin="12,186,0,0" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="849" />
</Grid>
```

Yet, when I add it to the window that it's going to be in, it looks like this:

[image: Added]

XAML for the Window is:

```
<Grid>
    <SurveyReport:SurveyReport Margin="0,12,0,0" Height="727" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1425" />
</Grid>
```

Now, when I run the program, it appears the way that it should. But in the designer, it looks all messed up. All my other custom controls look the way that they should. It's just this one that is giving me issues. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Post the relevant XAML.

Comment: Edited to add the XAML.

Comment: Your XAML looks really bad. I suggest you learn to do layout in WPF and forget using the visual designer. It creates bad quality, unmaintainable, resolution-dependent, fixed-size XAML that is virtually useless.

Comment: @HighCore: Awesome. Yeah. Thanks. I'm in the process of learning.

Comment: My guess is that the designer is having trouble resolving the StaticResource reference and this messes up the layout when it attempts to render the Labels.  Try removing the resource style from one of your labels and see if that causes it to position properly in the designer.  In general, I've found the XAML visual designer doesn't work particularly well, especially when nesting controls.

Comment: @DanBryant: But it doesn't have any trouble with any other custom controls, and I use that StaticResource for all my labels.